# My phone app is suddenly crashing because of the main.m file

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

Suddenly when I try to run my app it immediately goes to the main.m file and shows me this SIGABRT error which I'm going to assume is Signal abort.  I just can't figure out why that is happening.  And I'm not sure what I am looking at in my debugging area.  Please help!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Mct2AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Mct2AppDelegate   
class]));
}  

}
```

Debugger Output:

> Attaching to process 8004.
>   Pending breakpoint 1 - ""main.m":17" resolved
>   Couldn't register com.ebonybutler.Mct2 with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Second Debugger Output since restart:

> 2012-02-29 16:46:45.561 Mct2[319:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "Menu" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x13bb052 0x154cd0a 0x1363a78 0x13639e9 0xd7f0d 0xd83a9 0x2415e2 0xd85cb 0x25e4 0x13bcec9 0x155c2 0x1555a 0xbab76 0xbb03f 0xba2fe 0x3aa30 0x3ac56 0x21384 0x14aa9 0x12a5fa9 0x138f1c5 0x12f4022 0x12f290a 0x12f1db4 0x12f1ccb 0x12a4879 0x12a493e 0x12a9b 0x2032 0x1fa5)
>   terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: Check the actual backtrace in the left sidebar. It's likely it's crashed somewhere in framework code, but it's showing you `main.m` because that's the topmost stack frame it actually has source for.

Comment: Please post the console output as a start. My crystal ball is in the shop this week. :)

Comment: I also have this in the output: **Attaching to process 8004.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""main.m":17" resolved
Couldn't register com.ebonybutler.Mct2 with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Current language:  auto; currently objective-c**

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix, if you're using iOS simulator, just close it down and rerun the project

Comment: I've tried closing down the project and even restarting my mac and I'm getting the same result.  Although before I couldn't even get the app to even show up.  Now its coming up but when I push the 'enter' button, it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

This is Happens because your application getting terminate.

Try the following things in the below order:

- Make sure all only one program is being debugged in XCode, close other running instances.
- shut down your system and restart it before doing third steps.
- Restart XCode, most of time this is take care of the issue.
- If you are running this on the device and is still not working restart the device and try again.

It Really Work.

Comment: Kamarshad, how do check to see if more than one program is being debugged?

Comment: @Maple some times instance of existing app remains in memory, i think so.In this case we should perform above steps.and one more step need to perform just shut down your system and restart it before doing second steps..

Comment: @Maple as you have updated you question, this is happening due to the connection of XIB not set. Properly check your View IBOulet Connection .As it clears from this Error '"-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "Menu" nib but the view outlet was not set."

Comment: I'm quite sure how to do that Kamarshad.  I'm sorry I'm fairly new to this.  Am I supposed to add 'IBOutlet' the delegate .h file?